# How can I get mouse cursor position in 'draw.selectionchange' event handler?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl-draw

I am using `@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw` to draw polygons on a map and would like to show context popup when user selects a polygon.

I think the only feasible event I can use is `draw.selectionchange` which is [a custom event](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/main/src/render.js#L55) therefore no mouse cursor position available, but I need the position so as to show the popup.

I created [a simple app](https://mnkdd7.csb.app/) to demo this. The `draw.selectionchange` event is printed in the log after you draw or select a polygon. A map reference is provided in the event payload but I also don't find a way to get cursor position via map.

Any advice is appreciated.